# Computing the appproximation numbers of an operator $T:\ell_2\longrightarrow\ell_2$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm practicing for an operator theory exam, and doing exercises from previous exams. One of them is this, it is a test and it is assumed that there is only one correct solution.

> Let $T:\ell_2\longrightarrow\ell_2$ be a linear bounded operator defined as
> $$T\Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\Bigr)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x,e_{2n}\rangle e_n,$$
> where
> $$e_n=(0,0,\ldots,\underbrace{1}_n,\ldots),\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
> Show which of the following statements is true:
>
> (a) $T'=T$.
>
> (b) $a_n(T)=1,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> (c) $T\circ T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigl(\langle x,e_{2n}\rangle\bigr)^2e_n$.

In this case, $T'$ is the transpose operator of $T$ and $a_n$ is the $n$-th approximation number, defined as
$$a_n(T):=\inf\bigl\{\|T-S\|:\ S\in\mathcal{L}(\ell_2),\  \dim S(\ell_2)<n\bigr\}.\tag{1}$$

If I'm not wrong, I can write, for simplicity
$$T(x_n)=(x_2,x_4,\ldots,x_{2n},\ldots)$$
and calculate the transpose operator
$$T'(y_n)=(0,y_1,0,y_2,\ldots,0,y_n,\ldots)$$
so the first option is false. The third is also trivially false, which leaves me as a good option the second one.

But how can I prove it directly? I am unable to apply the given definition $(1)$. I have an additional lemma from Diestel, Jarchow and Tonge, *Absolutely Summing Operators*, which says:

> Let the compact operator $u:H_1\longrightarrow H_2$ be represented as
> $$u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau_n\langle\cdot,e_n\rangle f_n,$$
> where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence in $H_1$, $(f_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence in $H_2$, an $(\tau_n)$ is a null sequence of scalars which satisfy
> $$0\leq\tau_{n+1}\leq\tau_n,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.\tag{2}$$
> Then, $\tau_n=a_n(u)$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My class notes relax this conditions a bit and do not require that $(\tau_n)$ be a null sequence, only that the condition $(2)$ be met.

Anyway, I don't think this can be applied in this case, because $T$ is not a compact operator.

Any idea how I can continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $S=0$ then $\|T-S\|=\|T\|=1$ and $a_n(T)\le1$.

Take $S$ with $\dim \ S(l^2)<n$ and $\|S-T\|= 1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon\ge0$. Take $y\in R(S)^\perp$, $\|y\|=1$, which is possible as the range of $S$ is finite-dimensional. Then by definition of $T$ there is $x$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ and $Tx=y$.
Then
$$
(1-\epsilon)^2 \ge \|(S-T)x\|^2 = \|Sx\|^2+\|Tx\|^2 + 2Re(\langle Sx,Tx\rangle)
=\|Sx\|^2 +1.
$$
This implies $0\le\|Sx\|^2 \le \epsilon^2 -2\epsilon = \epsilon(1-2\epsilon)$, and $\epsilon\le\frac12$, so $a_n(T)\ge\frac12$.
In addition,
$$
1=\|Tx\|\le \|Sx\| +\|(S-T)x\| \le \sqrt{\epsilon^2 -2\epsilon} + 1-\epsilon,
$$
which implies $\epsilon \le \sqrt{\epsilon^2 -2\epsilon}$. And $\epsilon$ has to be zero, and $a_n(T)\ge1$.

Comment: So, if $\|T\|=1$ then $a_n(T)=1$?

Comment: No. Only $a_n(T)\le 1$, as in the first part of my answer. The second part uses the particular structure of $T$ to conclude $a_n(T)=1$.